# Fizz Buzz: Ideal solution

Tags: c++

So, Fizz Buzz is a very simple problem and there are quite a lot of solutions to this problem. In a recent interview, the interviewer asked me to write a function for Fizz Buzz, So I single-handedly came up with the following approach.

```
void fizz_buzz(int range) {
    for(auto i = 1; i < range; ++i) {
        if(i % 15 == 0)
            cout << "FizzBuzz" << "\n";
        else if(i % 3 == 0)
            cout << "Fizz" << "\n";
        else if(i % 5 == 0)
            cout << "Buzz" << "\n";
        else 
            cout << i << "\n";
    }
}
```

And then the interviewer asked me what If I wanted to modify Fizz Buzz for 3 and 7 then in your code multiple conditional statements would have to be changed.

So, I wrote the following snippet:

```
void fizz_buzz(int range) {
    //Notice that we don't need to check for divisibility by both values now
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 1; i < range; ++i) {
        string str;
        if(i % 3 == 0)
            str += "Fizz";

        if(i % 5 == 0)
            str += "Buzz";

        if(str.empty())
            str += to_string(i);

        cout << str << " ";
    }
}
```

But, again the interviewer said that he is not satisfied with this approach also. What should be an ideal way to approach Fizz Buzz then?

Comment: Optimal solutions are not the intent of the Fizz Buzz test. At the Fizz Buzz level I'm interested in two things from an applicant: Is the code coherent and well-structured and does it work?

Comment: Your first example is missing `else cout << i << "\n";` but aside from that, I would have accepted either of your solutions, and I think your interviewer is just too picky.

Comment: 3 & 7 or 3 & 5 for the second one?

Comment: @drescherjm, So, it's not essentially 3 or 5. The interviewer wanted me to write the snippet which required a minimum number of changes in the code if changed for other values.

Comment: @ArunSuryan `void fizz_buzz(int range, int fizz=3, int buzz=5)` --  Then you use `fizz` and `buzz` in the function instead of hardcoding 3 and 5.  Would that be satisfactory?

Comment: I think the answer is excellent however the suggestion from @PaulMcKenzie likely would have been enough for that question depending on the level of programmer position you are interviewing for.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it's a nice and easy one.

Comment: @ArunSuryan -- Maybe the interviewer wanted to see if you could make the function flexible, and at the same time not break any existing code that called the fizzbuzz function.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie that would break any code calling `fizzbuzz` through a function pointer. No?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need an entire string just to check if anything is printed, a single `bool` would do. Besides that, I'd collect the numbers in an array for easy extensibility. Other than that, your second solution seems pretty okay. Here's my go at it:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <utility>

void fizzbuzz(int const range) noexcept {
    constexpr std::pair<int, char const*> pairs[] {
        {3, "Fizz"}, {5, "Buzz"}, {7, "Fuzz"}, {13, "Bizz"}
    };

    for (int i = 1; i < range; ++i) {
        bool none = true;
        for (auto const& [num, str] : pairs) {
            if (i % num == 0) {
                std::printf("%s", str);
                none = false;
            } 
        }

        if (none) {
            std::printf("%d", i);
        }
        std::putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Comment: Any special reason for `printf` instead of `cout`?

Comment: @Evg `cout` could potentially throw and I wanted to make the function `noexcept`